# C++ - read ANSI encoded text as wide character string

Tags: c++

My aim is to read ANSI encoded texts. But for some reasons I'm using fgetws() (not fgets) function and of course file is opened in binary mode. Here is the short code which demonstrates my problem

```
  bool testfunc(wchar_t path[])
  {
     wchar_t buffer[10];

     if( FILE * fr=_wfopen(path,L"rb") )
     {
        fgetws(buffer,sizeof(buffer),fr);
        fclose(fr);
        return true;
     }
     else return false;
  }
```

when I call this function and pass ANSI encoded text file path as an argument, there arises Access Violation error in run time. It seems that the error occurs when the text size is large enough.  I can not figure out where the problem is.

Comment: Define ANSI encoding! Maybe you mean that your file contains only ASCII characters? Or do you talk of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code ??

Comment: Yes, I meant it has ASCII characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the doc, `fgetws` 's second parameter is the number of wide chars in the array, not bytes, so:

```
fgetws(buffer,sizeof(buffer)/sizeof(*buffer),fr);
```

A useful classic macro for this is is:

```
#define countof(x) (sizeof(x)/sizeof(*(x)))
```

Or a fancy C++ template:

```
template <typename T, int N>
int countof(T (&a)[N])
{
    return N;
}
```

Comment: The above answer makes sense only (and that is uncommon) if the file use fixed-size Unicode encoding which fits into `wchar_t`. Most Unicode files are UTF-8 encoded, and if the contained chars are only ASCII, the above answer is wrong, unless the `LC_CTYPE` environment variable matches the encoding of the file....

Comment: Basile, thank you for your comment. Yes I know that the answer fits only UTF-16 encoded texts. What I was searching for. But anyway, your answer is very interesting also.

Answer (score 1):

If the file contains only [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii) characters (remember that ASCII is a subset of [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode), and that the size of `wchar_t` is implementation specific and might fit for some fixed-width encoding of a subset of Unicode characters; so `wchar_t` is not very portable) you need to convert each individual ASCII character to its wide character equivalent:

```
{
#define SIZE 80
    char cbuf[SIZE];
    wchar_t wbuf[SIZE];
    char* pc;
    wchar_t* pw;
    memset (cbuf, 0, sizeof(cbuf));
    memset (wbuf, 0, sizeof(wbuf));
    fgets (cbuf, SIZE, fr);
    for ((pc=cbuf), (pw=wbuf); pc<cbuf+SIZE && *pc != 0; pc++, pw++)
      *pw = (wchar_t) *pc;
}
```

P.S. read carefully the *NOTES* of [fgetws(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgetws) man page. It can be understood as scary.